# Determinant of integer matrix with armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I have a function whose parameter is `const arma::imat & A`. And apart from other things I want to calculate determinant of input matrix A. Therefore I did

```
int det = arma::det(A);
```

but during compilation I get following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'det'
int det = arma::det(A);
```

I tried google but found nothing that would address this problem. Any ideas please what might be the problem?

Comment: I'm not well confortable with armadillo, but reading the doc I think you have to use `conv_to<type>::from` to be able to call `det` which is defined for `imat::mat`.

Comment: Works as magic! Please do post your comment as answer and I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the doc, I think you have to use `conv_to<type>::from` to be able to call `det` which is defined for `imat::mat`.